# What do you call a method or library which is old and shouldn't be used anymore?

Tags: vocabulary

There has to be a name for this.  I'm thinking degraded or unused (old isn't descriptive enough).  Has anyone come up with something descriptive to call this?

Comment: "Mysterious portal to the Ancient World."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Deprecated](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~Clem.Baker-Finch/Java/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) (in java) or [Obsolete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22kk2b44(VS.90).aspx) (in c#)

Comment: Note: it's not 'depreciated' as some people like to call it. Depreciated relates to the loss of value of an asset over time.

Answer (score 6):

[Deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation)

Answer (score 5):

You should use: deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Obsolete for .NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx